# Angular watch function not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search textbox. I am putting value and on press of enter key it is giving me result.

This is my Html Code

```
     <input type="text" class="filter-input" my-enter="submitFilterForm()" ng-model="vm.query" auto-focus />
```

This is my JS File

```
              $scope.$watch("vm.query", function(name) {
            $scope.validationError = false;
            console.log("value of query is", name);
            filterStateService.updateSearchQuery(name);
        });
```

my-enter is my custom directive. On ng-model="query" I have defined a $watch function in my JS.

If I am entering value in textbox character by character it is printing $scope.query correct. But if i am directly copying the value and pasting into textBox it is coming as null. $watch is not working when i am directly copy and paste value in searchbox. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: Why are you using `$watch` when using a inbound `ngModel`? You could use `ngChange` to hook a listeren on change ...

Comment: I need this value in another js thats y keeping it global.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ng-change and not watch function:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="filter-input" my-enter="submitFilterForm()" ng-model="query" ng-change="queryChanged" ge-auto-focus />
```

JS:

```
function queryChanged(){
     $scope.query //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $watch, it should work:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.query', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('newValue:', newValue);
    console.log('oldValue:', oldValue);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jbbrwcky/rufe5da1/6/

You need to pass an argument into the $watch rather than looking at $scope.query as you were.

Comment: Hey i tried your fiddler in safari browser it is working fine but in my code when i am doing Command+V , watch is not getting triggered. I updated my Code as you said please have a look.

Comment: Whereabouts is your $watch? Is it in the directive's controller, or the page controller?

Comment: I didn't added $watch as a dependency in my JS

Comment: $watch function is working fine it is not working only when we are copy pasting data directly

Comment: Which is odd given that the fiddle works. I'll check on safari when I get home, see if there's something odd with it.

Comment: The link which you gave for fiddle was working i tried in safari but my code is not working when i am doing Command+V $watch is not getting triggered

Comment: Did you get chance to look into this issue?